# MySQL: How to get averge comments posted per day by each member?

Tags: php, mysql

i need some help with getting the average comments posted per day by each member. I would like to get it using mysql query rather than using multiple queries and calculation in php.

These are the tables and their fields:

1. members

   - num (primary)
   - createdDate (timestamp)
2. posts

   - num (primary)
   - createdDate (timestamp)
   - member_num
3. comments

   - num (primary)
   - createdDate (timestamp)
   - member_num
   - posts_num

Is this possible to get results like this using a single query or minimal:

```
+--------------+------------------------+
|  member_num  |  avg_comments_per_day  |
+--------------+------------------------+
|  5           |  10                    |
+--------------+------------------------+
|  24          |  7                     |
+--------------+------------------------+
|  33          |  5                     |
+--------------+------------------------+
|  8           |  1                     |
+--------------+------------------------+
|  9           |  1                     |
+--------------+------------------------+
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i couldn't create my code, i had no clue from where to begin, so i asked help here.

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
SELECT member_num,
       COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(createdDate AS DATE)) AS avg_comments_per_day
  FROM comments
 GROUP
    BY member_num
;
```

That will give the total number of comments by each user, divided by the total number of days on which that user has posted any comments. (That seems like the simplest notion of "average". If you want something different, please clarify.)

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you would need to have a table with all possible dates that you can join against.  So something like:

```
dates table
--------------

date
2001-01-01
2001-01-02
...
2030-12-31
```

Obviously you can adjust the start and end dates as needed.  The reason you need this is that you need to have a way to calculate the dates where the use has 0 comments, which won't show up in your comments table.

You then need to join this table with your comments table:

```
SELECT
  c.member_num AS `member`,
  d.`date` AS `date`,
  COUNT(c.num) AS `count`
FROM dates AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments AS c
  ON d.`date` = DATE(c.createdDate)
WHERE d.`date` BETWEEN '????-??-??' AND '????-??-??'
GROUP BY `member`, `date`
```

Note that I have added a date range here, so you can calculate the average only over the period you are interested in. Without doing this, you will get the average across all days in the dates table. Of course this only gets you part of the way. You still need to average this information, so use the above query as a subselect in the final query:

```
SELECT
    `member`,
    AVG(`count`) AS `daily_average`
FROM
    (SELECT
      c.member_num AS `member`,
      d.`date` AS `date`,
      COUNT(c.num) AS `count`
    FROM dates AS d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN comments AS c
      ON d.`date` = DATE(c.createdDate)
    WHERE d.`date` BETWEEN '????-??-??' AND '????-??-??'
    GROUP BY `member`, `date`) AS `comment_counts`
GROUP BY `member`
```

Of course, this query would perform really poorly, as you wouldn't be using an index on the join between comments and dates.  If you need to do this query on a regular basis, my suggestion is to actually build a table where you can update comment counts stats into it properly.

Answer (score 0):

ruakh's or mike's approach should work for your case.

But you should consider storing these information in a separate table that you update either on every comment or once a day (or both).

Let's say that a single user writes 10 posts a day, then It's 3650 comments a year, after being on the website for 10 years (or less) then you have 365000 comments from that single user. Calculating the average comment per day, on rune-time, might add upp in calculation time, especially if you have to do it many times a day for very many users.

So instead of calculating the average comments per day, everytime you need the data, then just have a seperate table that has

```
userId
avgComments
```

It's much more efficient to fetch that single index, rather than doing the calculation every single time you need the data.